# Why do some sprites stop rendering when I zoom in using a translation matrix?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm using Monogame to build a game and I had the camera working for a long time, I recently changed all my sprites from 64*64 to 32*32 and I'm having trouble with the camera zoom and drawing sprites (view GIF), I am using the depth property in the Spritebatch to order my sprites.

### Draw method:

```
_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
        SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, camera.TranslationMatrix);

        tileMap.Draw(_spriteBatch);
        sceneObjectHandler.Draw(_spriteBatch);
        player.Draw(_spriteBatch);
_spriteBatch.End();
```

### **GIF:**

[image: What happens when I zoom]

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It would probably be useful to see the code inside the `player.Draw` method. When you say you're "using the depth property" what exactly does that look like?

Comment: All of my draw methods are similar to the player, heres the player: `spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)dimensions.X, (int)dimensions.Y),null,Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(0,0), SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);`      I don't think it's to do with the depth property because it is working when I zoom out enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Anyone comes across this post in the future I found the solution:

When creating the translation matrix for scaling the view use:

```
Matrix.CreateScale(scale, scale, 1)
```

instead of:

```
Matrix.CreateScale(scale)
```

So that the Z-index does not affect the scaling